# Start a program after 45 mins of overall activity

Tags: bash

hi I want to setup something like a smart alarm reminders, which will help to have a break after some intervals of activity. e.g. I want to know if the system can detect me, like if I am typing in...etc.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. But you can take a look at Wakatime's source code. It detects when you are doing stuff on your text editor and sends messages to its API. Maybe the tracking part you can learn from it. https://github.com/wakatime/wakatime

Comment: Please clarify a bit more concrete what your goal is.

Comment: Maybe this thread is helpful to you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222606/detecting-keyboard-mouse-activity-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

I use this script

`at now + 1 minutes < <(echo 'notify-send "DO SOMETHING"')`

When I run it, it will print the popup "DO SOMETHING" via the nodify-send command. It will do this after at most 1 minute

That is, if i run this command at 11:07:51, it will run at 11:08:00, so only 9 seconds after i executed it.

However, for time intervals of 45 minutes, 1 minute may not matter that much.

I don't know a way to detect the start of activity, but hope this command is useful. I used it to when playing some online games, to know when to train troops/ attack :)